# Proving convergence of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, recursion

Let the following recursively defined sequence:

$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2} a_n +2,$

$a_1=\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Prove that $a_n$ converges to 4 by subtracting 4 from both sides.

When I do that, I get:
$2(\frac{1}{2} a_{n+1} -2)=(\frac{1}{2} a_n -2)$, so $y=2y$, 
which is true only for $0$. But I'm not sure how to formally use this in a definition of convergence?

Comment: take a look [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=recurrence+a%28n%2B1%29%3D%281%2F2%29+a%28n%29%2B2%2C+a%281%29%3D1%2F2 ]

Comment: i upvoted +1 you all answers, now upvote me! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $b_n=a_n-4$. Then $b_1=-7/2$ and 
$$
b_{n+1}=a_{n+1}-4=\frac{1}{2}a_n+2-4=\frac{1}{2}(a_n-4)=\frac{1}{2}b_n.
$$ 
Thus
$$
b_n=\frac{b_{n-1}}{2}=\frac{b_{n-2}}{2^2}=\cdots=\frac{b_{1}}{2^{n-1}}=-\frac{7}{2^n},
$$
and finally
$$
a_n=4-\frac{7}{2^n}.
$$
Hence
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=4.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Just a generalization of the approach for you. Note that 
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{2}a_{n-1}+2
$$
So if you subtract this expression from the $a_{n+1}$ you have above, you get rid of the constant. Also denote $\Delta a_{n+1}=a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ and you get:

$$
\Delta a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2} \Delta a_{n}=\frac{1}{2^2} \Delta a_{n-1}=\ldots =\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \Delta a_{2}
$$

If you sum over $n$ the LHS you get a telescoping sum: $\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{n+1}=a_{N+1}-a_1$. Since $a_2=2 \frac{1}{4}$ and $a_1 = 0.5$ you get (using geometric sum $\sum_{n=1}^{N}  \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=2(1-(\frac{1}{2})^{N+1})$

$$
a_{N+1}=0.5+(2.25-0.5) \cdot 2 \cdot \Bigg(1-(\frac{1}{2})^{N+1} \bigg)
$$
and if you take the limit as $N \to \infty$ you get $0.5+3.5=4$.

Answer (score 1):

Use contractive condition to prove it is Cauchy  sequence which will imply it converges:

Use: $|a(n+2) - a(n+1)| < k|a(n+1) - a(n)|$

If $0 < k < 1$ then it's a Cauchy  sequence.
On solving $k$ comes out to to be a half (so, $1/2$).
Hence sequence converges.

To find limit: say limit is $x$.
As $n$ tends to infinity so $a(n+1)$ is almost equal to $a(n)$, so putting $x$ in place of $a(n)$ and $a(n+1)$ that is:
$$x = x/2 + 2$$

so limit is $x=4$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $2(\frac{1}{2}a_{n+1}-2)=\frac{1}{2}a_{n}-2$. So, you have a sequence $y_n$ where $y_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}y_n$. This is a bounded decreasing sequence, and hence has a limit, say $y$. Then $y$ satisfies $y=\frac{1}{2}y$ so $y=0$

Comment: note that $a_n\to 4$ when $n\to\infty$.. [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=recurrence+a%28n%2B1%29%3D%281%2F2%29+a%28n%29%2B2%2C+a%281%29%3D1%2F2 ]

Comment: Yes- that doesn't contradict what I have mentioned. y=lim $ y_n=0$ and $y_n=(\frac{1}{2}a_n-2)$. So limit of $a_n=4$

Comment: you should add "... or $y=4$... " to include a non trivial solution

Comment: But how can I prove that this is a bounded sequence? I see it graphically, but not formally.

Comment: Define $y_n$ as I mentioned in the answer. $y_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}y_n$ which is obviously decreasing. Very formally, the ratio of $y_{n+1}/y_n <1$ and hence decreasing.

Comment: @burgundy7 *any convergent sequence it is also bounded*

Comment: @janmarqz I think the issue here is that we show it's bounded decreasing and hence convergent.

Comment: really solving the recurrence shows its convergence :P

Comment: Would it be appropriate to say that every decreasing sequence is bounded?

Comment: @burgundy7: This is a decreasing sequence of positive terms. Trivially bounded below by $0$ and bounded above by the first term of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this recurrence is 
$$a_n=4-\frac{7}{2^n},$$ 
so $a_n$ converges to $4$.