# Recursive relation

Tags: recursive-algorithms

Sequence defined by recursive relation $a_{n+1}=\alpha a_n +2$

Prove that if $\left|\alpha\right|\lt1,$ the sequence has a limit independent of $a_1$.

I have seen this work for the case when $\alpha=1/2$, but I'm not sure how to work out the math to generalize?

Comment: Well, show us how you do it for $\alpha=1/2$, maybe we can work it out together for the general case.

Comment: I asked a question about the specific case (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644049/convergence-of-sequence-proving), and I see from the recursive relation that results that the limit does not depend on $a_1$, and we could have replaced -7 with any other number. But I'm not sure how to get this nice result if I don't have the nice $b_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2} b_n$ relationship.

Comment: I maintain that if you think about some of the answers given to that earlier question, you will see how to modify them to work for other values of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, if $a_n$ converges then the limit satisfies the equation $x=\alpha x+2$, and thus $x=\dfrac{2}{1-\alpha}$. We hence set
$$
b_n=a_n-\frac{2}{1-\alpha}.
$$
Then we have
$$
b_{n+1}=a_{n+1}-\frac{2}{1-\alpha}=\alpha\,a_n+2-\frac{2}{1-\alpha}
=\alpha\left(a_n-\frac{2}{1-\alpha}\right)=\alpha\,b_n.
$$
Hence
$$
b_n=\alpha\, b_{n-1}=\alpha^2 b_{n-2}=\cdots=\alpha^{n-1} b_1=
\alpha^{n-1}\left(a_1-\frac{2}{1-\alpha}\right),
$$
and thus
$$
a_n=b_n+\frac{2}{1-\alpha}=\alpha^{n-1}\left(a_1-\frac{2}{1-\alpha}\right)+\frac{2}{1-\alpha},
$$
and therefore
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\frac{2}{1-\alpha}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\alpha x+2$ is a contracting map (because of $|\alpha| < 1$ , the iteration 
 converges to the (unique) solution of the equation

x = $\alpha x+2$

for any starting value. This follows from banachs fixpoint theorem.

The limit is given by

$$\frac{2}{1-\alpha}$$

Comment: I think the fixed point theorem is overkill for this problem, don't you?

Comment: Maybe, but I did not find an answer without it. Does the general approach monotonon sequence / bounded sequence work here ?

Comment: It's a first-order linear recurrence relation, and there are standard techniques for solving it (though even that may be overkill, but it's what occurs to me).

Answer (score 1):

$$a_{n+1} = \alpha a_n + 2$$

The first few terms in this sequence are:

$$a_1,\,\alpha a_1 + 2,\, \alpha^2 a_1 + 2\alpha + 2,\, \alpha^3 a_1 + 2 \alpha^2 + 2\alpha + 2$$

This should make it clear that the $n^{\text{th}}$ term in the sequence will be (for any $n \neq 1$):

$$a_n = \alpha^{n-1} a_1 + \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} 2\alpha^{k-1}$$

The summation part of this explicit formula is a geometric series, and so converges for $|\,\alpha\,| < 1$. The other part goes to zero for $|\,\alpha\,| < 1$. Thus, the sequence must converge.